# Get all post from a friend in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I would like to get/download all the posts on a friend's wall in Facebook (at least the text, although most of these posts also have images).

Is there any easy way to do that (using any script, application, procedure, etc)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t, and you shouldn´t be able to, for privacy reasons.

You can only get access to a wall by authorizing the owner of the wall with the neccessary permissions (read_stream, user_posts, ...). Check out the docs for detailed information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

Comment: _you shouldn´t be able to_? Come on, the only reason they are implementing these rules is to eliminate alternative feed readers. I seriously doubt that any of those readers is hard harvesting any "private" data. It's user's responsibility to choose to whom he will grant the access to. This might end up with users giving out their passwords to the readers so the reader can parse feed directly from the page. Now tell me what's worse.

Comment: i would not want any app to be able to read my posts just because one of my friends authorized it. not even public posts. giving out passwords? who would do that? that would be completely illegal anyway.

Comment: i mean....would you really give away your facebook password for something you could have by just visiting facebook.com directly? ;)

Comment: Well, yes, I really don't see any difference between this and authorizing Thunderbird / Outlook client to access Gmail mailbox over IMAP. I am using FB feed reader (it works like RSS) to see what's happening without even opening Facebook. For now it works via their API only with read_stream permissions. Since 1st May? What are my options?

Comment: you can still use read_stream after 1st may with an app you created

Comment: the big difference between this and authorizing an email client is that you get only your own mailbox in the email client. with the facebook feed, you get all the entries of your friends, who did not necessarily direct them at you. also, with the facebook login credentials you can do a lot more.

Comment: I'll try it anothey way: what is the difference between me reading the status messages in the browser and in the reader? I mean only from the other user's perspective. The only person reading the messages is me, through a 3rd party app. And you say that I get all the entries of my friends - that's not true. The read_stream permission works simillar way the normal FB feed does, it doesn't let you access posts that you can't view throught FB in the browser.

Comment: through a 3rd party app. that´s the main problem. you can never know what happens in the background in the 3rd party app when you use it ;)

Comment: and i did not say "you get all the entries of your friend". where did i say that? of course you only get those visible to you on facebook.

Comment: Well, you don't even know what the FB does with your data. Let's end it there. :-) This measure against 3rd party apps will probably make me visit FB less. Sadly I am a fish in the sea...

Comment: better facebook than some random developer ;) - well, some like the changes (like me), some don´t. in the end it´s up to facebook. it´s their platform, they can do all they want with it, if people don´t like it they can leave :)